# C++ Error: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, class, bisection

I am trying to solve a quadratic equation using the bisection method. When trying to evaluate the roots I get this error: "no matching function for call".

```
#include "assign4.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   solution s;
   double root;

   cout << "Enter interval endpoints: ";
   cin >> s.xLeft >> s.xRight;

   cout << "Enter tolerance: ";
   cin >> s.epsilon;

   root = s.bisect (s.xLeft, s.xRight, s.epsilon, s.f, s.error);

   if (!(s.error))
      cout << "Root found at " << root << "\nValue of f(x) at root is: " << s.f(root);
   else
      cout << "The solution of a quadratic equation with coefficients: " << endl;
      cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << endl;
      cout << "has not been found." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The error occurs where root = ... it seems to have a problem with my function f but I don't understand what is wrong. The following two bits of code are my class and class implementation files. We just started working with classes so I am uncertain if my problem lies there or simply in the above code.

```
#ifndef ASSIGN4_H
#define ASSIGN4_H

class solution {

public:
   double xLeft, xRight;
   double epsilon;
   bool error;

   double bisect(double, double, double, double f(double), bool&);
   double f(double);
};
#endif // ASSIGN4_H
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include "assign4.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double solution::bisect (double xLeft, double xRight, double epsilon, double func(double), bool& error) {
   double xMid;
   double fLeft, fRight;
   double fMid;

   fLeft = f(xLeft);
   fRight = f(xRight);

   error = (fLeft * fRight) > 0;
   if (error)
      return -999.0;

   while (fabs (xLeft - xRight) > epsilon) {
      xMid = (xLeft + xRight) / 2.0;
      fMid = f (xMid);

      if (fMid == 0.0)
         return xMid;
      else if (fLeft * fMid < 0.0)
         xRight = xMid;
      else
         xLeft = xMid;

      cout << "New Interval is [" << xLeft << ", " << xRight << "]" << endl;
   }

return (xLeft + xRight) / 2.0;
}

double solution::f (double x) {
   return ((5 * pow(x,2.0)) + (5 * x) + 3);
}
```

Comment: Show us the exact error message please.

Comment: Why pass `s.f` at all?  It's part of the same object as `bisect`, and it's perfectly reasonable for `bisect` to know `f` exists and to call `f` at the appropriate time.

Comment: Your code is kind of missing the point of using classes and objects. An object should wrap related data and functions together. Since bisect is part of your solution class, and solution already has all of the data, then your bisect function doesn't need the data in function parameters.

Comment: That makes sense. So I can just say `double solution::bisect (){`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pointers to member functions.

Change

```
double bisect(double, double, double, double f(double), bool&);
```

to

```
double bisect(double, double, double, double (solution::*f)(double), bool&);
```

in declaration and definition.

Change the call from

```
root = s.bisect (s.xLeft, s.xRight, s.epsilon, s.f, s.error);
```

to

```
root = s.bisect (s.xLeft, s.xRight, s.epsilon, &solution::f, s.error);
```

This is what I have that compiles and links successfully for me.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <typeinfo>
 #include <math.h>

 using namespace std;

 class solution {

 public:
    double xLeft, xRight;
    double epsilon;
    bool error;

    double bisect(double, double, double, double (solution::*f)(double), bool&);
    double f(double);
 };

 using namespace std;

 double solution::bisect (double xLeft, double xRight, double epsilon, double (solution::*func)(double), bool& error) {
    double xMid;
    double fLeft, fRight;
    double fMid;

    fLeft = (this->*func)(xLeft);
    fRight = (this->*func)(xRight);

    error = (fLeft * fRight) > 0;
    if (error)
       return -999.0;

    while (fabs (xLeft - xRight) > epsilon) {
       xMid = (xLeft + xRight) / 2.0;
       fMid = (this->*func)(xMid);

       if (fMid == 0.0)
          return xMid;
       else if (fLeft * fMid < 0.0)
       {
          xRight = xMid;
          fRight = fMid;
       }
       else
       {
          xLeft = xMid;
          fLeft = fMid;
       }

       cout << "New Interval is [" << xLeft << ", " << xRight << "]" << endl;
    }

 return (xLeft + xRight) / 2.0;
 }

 double solution::f (double x) {
    return ((5 * pow(x,2.0)) + (5 * x) + 3);
 }

 int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    solution s;
    double root;

    cout << "Enter interval endpoints: ";
    cin >> s.xLeft >> s.xRight;

    cout << "Enter tolerance: ";
    cin >> s.epsilon;

    root = s.bisect (s.xLeft, s.xRight, s.epsilon, &solution::f, s.error);

    if (!(s.error))
       cout << "Root found at " << root << "\nValue of f(x) at root is: " << s.f(root) << endl;
    else
    {
       cout << "The solution of a quadratic equation with coefficients: " << endl;
       // cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << endl;
       cout << "has not been found." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `assign4test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
assign4test.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘solution::bisect(double&, double&, double&, double (*)(double), bool&)’
assign4.h:16: note: candidates are: double solution::bisect(double, double, double, double (solution::*)(double), bool&)
assign4test.cpp:24: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

Apologies, I forgot to add the error message.

Comment: If you changed `solution::f` to a static member function, my suggestion won't work. My suggestion will work only if `solution::f` is a non-static member function.

Comment: I just removed the static syntax from the declaration and now I am getting this error.

`assign4test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
assign4test.cpp:24: error: cannot call member function ‘double solution::f(double)’ without object`

Comment: @Ryan I just added code to the answer that compiles and links successfully for me. Hope that helps.

Comment: @R Sahu I changed everything to match your revised post above and I am still getting the same 'undefined reference to' errors.

Comment: @Ryan `undefined reference to` error is a link time error. Can you post the entire linker error message?

Comment: `/tmp/ccI5z1wR.o: In function `main':
assign4test.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `solution::f(double)'
assign4test.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `solution::bisect(double, double, double, double (*)(double), bool&)'
assign4test.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `solution::f(double)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`


This is the entire error message.

Comment: Looks like the object file that contains the definitions of the functions was not provided to the linker. If you are using `g++`, you can use: `g++ -o assign4test assign4test.cpp assign4.cpp`. That should work.

Comment: Ok so some good news, it now compiles. However, when I run the program it does not successfully find roots for an equation I know has roots on a specific interval. The equation I am using is 4x^2+7x+3 which should have roots at -1 and -0.75. I think perhaps the error is originating from how I am calculating my error variable but I am not certain.

Comment: It should be easy for you to figure out the calculation errors, I think.

Comment: I noticed that in `bisect`, the input argument `func` is not used. Instead, `f` is used. You should fix that before you run into strange behavior when you start using a different function.

Comment: Yes, I found that error shortly after I posted the original question but fixing it did not change any errors.

Comment: @Ryan I fixed the logic in the `while` block in `bisect`. With that change, the function works for me.

Answer (score 3):

The 4th  parameter is a function pointer,

```
double bisect(double, double, double, double f(double), bool&);
```

When you call this function:

```
root = s.bisect (s.xLeft, s.xRight, s.epsilon, s.f, s.error);
```

While the member fiction `double f(double)` is not the same type as that parameter because this is C++ member function and not static, so the 'this' parameter is added this member function when compiling.

type add the static key word to the function.

Comment: I tried this and still got errors saying I have an undefined reference.

`assign4test.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `solution::f(double)'
assign4test.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `solution::bisect(double, double, double, double (*)(double), bool&)'
assign4test.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `solution::f(double)'`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for a function pointer is usually: `double (*f)(double)`. Aside from that, you are attempting to pass a member function through a non-member-function pointer. Since your function does not use any member variables, the simplest solution would be to make it `static`:

```
class solution {
  // ...
  static double f(double);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with your callback function. Typically you get that kind of compiler error when you use an incorrect function call. If you want this kind of callback function, you may want to look into function pointers.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html